# Incorrect syntax causing "This value is not a function and cannot be applied"

Tags: functional-programming, f#

```
let compoundInterest initial monthly years (interest : decimal) =
    interest * (1.0m + interest) pown years

compoundInterest 100.0m 100.0m 5.0m 0.1m
```

I get `This value is not a function and cannot be applied.` which I believe is being caused by a syntax error. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The F# syntax for function application is:

```
f x
```

That is, whenever the compiler sees an expression followed by whitespace, then followed by another expression, the compiler sees it as function application, where the first expression is the function, and the second expression is the argument.

In your code, this is being parsed as function application:

```
(1.0m + interest) pown
```

where `(1.0m + interest)` is the function, and `pown` is the argument.

Later, once the compiler gets to type checking, it sees that `(1.0m + interest)` is not, in fact, a function, and so it complains: *this expression is not a function and cannot be applied*

I'm not exactly sure what you meant to do, but from variable names it looks like you're trying to calculate compound interest, and for that you're trying to raise (1+interest) to the power of years.

If that assumption is correct, then the way you're trying to call the `pown` function is wrong. This function expects two arguments, and the way to call it is to write the name of the function followed by the first argument, and then by the second:

```
pown x y
```

Or, applying this to your code:

```
pown (1.0m + interest) years
```